# Efficient extraction of anadromes

Tags: python

An anadrome is a proper sentence that when written in reverse constitutes a (possibly different) proper sentence **up to a possible change of spacing**. I have a file with 100 Million proper sentences and I would like to find all **sub**-sentences (divided by word boundaries) which are anadromes, by testing if their inverse is also in the file **when ignoring internal spaces**. My initial approach was to extract all sub-sentences and save them to a temporary file, create an in-memory set of their space-stripped inverses, and finally iterate over the temporary file and test if each line after space-stripping belongs to the set. This worked fine for smaller files but does not scale, as the set gets too large for memory. Other than replacing the in-memory set with an on-disk database, what could be done?

Edit: I ended up using an sqlite database with index. on a smaller set of 5 Million sentences using a db instead of an in-memory set takes 2x the time. With the full set, this is the only method that I found could complete the computation.

Comment: Maybe a way to reduce the data amount. Create a database of the words instead, reverse them and check for each sentence if first word shares characters with a stored word. If not, throw away the word. If so, try to match further.

Answer (score 1):

For each proper sentence you could try inverting it, and find all proper possible subtences.

Then for each inverted subsentence, you strip all the spaces.

You then do a regex-search in the original file, searching for using the space-stripped inverted-subsentence allowing for `\s?` in between characters.

For example `d\s?l\s?r\s?o\s?w\s?o\s?l\s?l\s?e\s?h` (inverted 'hello world') would match 'wlro woll eh' (inverted 'hello world' with crazy spacing, which would be in the original file *if it were a proper sentence*)

Comment: i implemented this with some small changes: " ?" instead of "\s?", and adding "\b" before and after the search string. the problem is that on a small test data this is 3000 times slower than my original approach.